# 5 Gallon Metal Can

Tags: water, bottle

I'm looking for a 5 gallon metal can (aluminum, galvanized, etc) to store drinking water. Old milk cans will be just fine. Is there a store which sells these kind of things? I live in Irvine.

Comment: Could you clarify please? Is this related to homebrewing? If so, where is Irvine (country, state)?

Comment: Irvine is a city in CA, USA. It's not that important. All I'm asking is where you'd buy home brewing equipment, specifically a 5 gallon metal can in California (you can use it to store water, for fermentation, etc).

Comment: Do they put drinking water in galvanized containers? I don't think so.

Comment: @brewchez why not? aluminum or galvanized are non-reactive and used for many things like milk cans and chicken fountain ...

Comment: Milk cans are an old invention. As such there are now stricter regulations on water foodstuffs and beverages come in contact with.  Galvanization involves zinc compounds which are toxic.  Milk today is entirely moved and stored in stainless steel.  Perhaps there are still some local farmers using galvanized cans or buckets, but for short contact times.  Galvanized containers are not recommended by the USDA or FDA for acidic food contact.  That certainly includes beer or wine.  Drinking water is likely fine for limited contact time. What does this question have to do with homebrewing?

Comment: This question is about water storage.  The questions does not specifically mention brewing.

Answer (score 1):

Homebrewers typically use 5g Stainless Steel Cornelius kegs to store beer in. A lot of homebrew stores carry them, they are also known as used Pepsi or Coke kegs. The kegs would have to be pressurized for storing water.